# fonts in emacs : how are they chosen?

Tags: emacs, unicode, fonts

When I run `M-x describe-font` on any font I choose on my macmini I get

```
name (opened by): -apple-Verdana-medium-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
       full name: Verdana
```

or

```
 name (opened by): -apple-Monaco-medium-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
       full name: Monaco
```

Every font has "-apple-" has prefix, and it does NOT display correctly unicode subscripts like $project_1$
[image]

whereas on my macbook I get :

```
name (opened by): -*-Monaco-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
       full name: Monaco:pixelsize=12:weight=normal:slant=normal:width=normal:spacing=100:scalable=true
```

Every font I might change has "-*-" for prefix, and I can see normally unicode subscripts :

[image]

Does anyone know how to force emacs to pick the font maker "*" instead of "apple"  ??

I suspect Monaco font is requested, but it does not identify the precise font used.

Comment: Here is what I use to set my default font for all frames -- it is at the outset of my `.emacs` file:  `(set-face-attribute 'default (selected-frame) :font "-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1") (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"))`  So, perhaps you could specify a font that you know is available on both systems.  You may experience differences if the OS versions are different.  All of my machines use Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and I'm going to keep using that rock solid OS until all 3 of my computers break.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 24.3.1 to 24.4.1 and the fonts are now "-*- ..." which display correctly unicode. I did not change configuration files

the mystery is still open, but at least it works.